Is there a way to get input data from a search bar in my flask navbar
I am trying to create a weather app where you search the name of a city in the search bar located in the navbar. I am using a context processor, but every time, it returns None.
I've tried this:
@app.context_processor
def weather_base():
    form = SearchForm()
    return dict(form=form)

And this:
@app.route("/daily", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def daily():
    form = SearchForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        post.searched = form.searched.data
        return render_template("daily.html", form=form, searched=post.searched, base=weather_base())
    return render_template("daily.html", form=form, base=weather_base())

But it keeps returning None when I run it. How can I make this work as intended?
